# Counting Polynomials Question

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, discrete-mathematics

This is a problem on my midterm review and I'm not sure at all how to approach it. If anyone could provide me with a solution including steps, I would be truly grateful as my exam is tomorrow morning.

Consider the set of degree $\leq d$ polynomials mod $p$, for some prime $p$. Fix $k < d$, and let $0 < a_1 < a_2 < ... < a_k < p$ be integers.

(a) How many degree $\leq d$ polynomials $P$ are there such that $P(a_1) = P(a_2) = ... = P(a_k) = 0$?

(b) How many polynomials are there of the form $P(x) = x^d + Q(x)$, where $Q$ has degree $\leq d - 1$, such that $P(a_1) = P(a_2) = ... = P(a_k) = 0$?

(c) How many degree $\leq d$ polynomials $P$ are there such that $P(a_1) \neq 0, \ P(a_2) \neq 0, \ ..., \ P(a_k) \neq 0$?

(Note: in general, when we talk about a degree $d$ polynomial, we typically mean to include the degenerate case of a degree $d - 1$ polynomial. This problem specifies $\leq d$ for clarity.)

Comment: Have you considered the polynomial $\Pi_{j=1}^k\left(x-a_j\right)$ multiplied by the set of polynomials $R(x)$ where the degree of $R$ is $c=d-k$?